# mostrar json ordenado

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('.ranking').innerHTML += '<p style="color:rgba(105, 109, 115,  0.465);">Jefes de incursión Actualizados con éxito...</p>';
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://pokemon-go-api.github.io/pokemon-go-api/api/quests.json';
request.open("GET", url);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        posts.quest.map( item => {
        document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `); 
        });
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="ranking">
   <div  class="ranking_block" id="raid1"></div>
</div>
```

Hola programadores buenas noches, me encuentro batallando con un codigo, tengo un json el cual me gustaria ordenarlos como la imagen:

[image: Ejemplo]

ordenarlos segun su tipo de mision en español.

estuve tratando de hacerlo pero ya me frustre, ya no se que hacer..
por favor ayuda!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer para ordenarlo? ¿Qué problema has tenido?

Comment: acceder y recorrer el json, pero no tuve exito

Comment: Podrías investigar cómo ordenar un arreglo de objetos, que es el problema que tienes: https://pokemon-go-api.github.io/pokemon-go-api/api/quests.json

Comment: donde puedo investigar eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear una función `OrderBy` sencilla, usando la función [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) y [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Algo así:

```
Array.prototype.OrderBy = function(exp, DIR = 1) {
  return this.sort( (a,b) =>  DIR * String(exp(a)).localeCompare(String(exp(b)), undefined, { numeric: true }));
}
```

Modo de uso

```
//                     v---Esta es la expresión por la cual se va ordenar
posts.OrderBy(a => a.quest.Spanish).map( item => {
           //algo
});
```

Puedes sustituir la expresión por la que tú quieres (que sea válida en el objeto), ejemplos

- a.quest.Korean
- a.rewards.type
- a.rewards.name.Italian

Y te ordenará por ella.

Además, para ordenar en orden inverso solo hay que agregar `-1`

```
posts.OrderBy(a => a.quest.Spanish,-1)
```

---

```
    document.querySelector('.ranking').innerHTML += '<p style="color:rgba(105, 109, 115,  0.465);">Jefes de incursión Actualizados con éxito...</p>';
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://pokemon-go-api.github.io/pokemon-go-api/api/quests.json';
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();

    request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            posts.OrderBy(a => a.quest.Spanish).map( item => {
            document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div>${item.rewards.name.Spanish}</div>`); 
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: gracias, Yussef
podrias hacer un ejemplo con lo quw yo estuve haciendo? por favor

Comment: @GAELVM Ahí agregue al final uno con el formato que tu tenías. Tu usas un `map` como un `for`, yo para este caso usaría un `for` (solo porque soy un viejo quisquilloso), el map es para convertir un array en otro, no para recorrer el array (aunque se pueda)

Comment: gracias, por responder yussef, acabo de hacer lo que pusiste pero no tengo respuesta, edite la publicación

Comment: @GAELVM No cambies la pregunta, porque pierde el sentido de la misma. Luego esta misma pregunta puede tener otras respuestas (yo la revertiré).  Entra acá para que veamos el asunto https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143209/yussef

Comment: gracias Yuseff, eres el mejor